# Javascript ES6 Difference between ()=>() and ()=>{}

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, reactjs

I have seen a code something like while learning React

```
const LinkCell = ({rowIndex, data, col, ...props}) => (
  <Cell {...props}>
    <a href="#">{data.getObjectAt(rowIndex)[col]}</a>
  </Cell>
);
```

Also, so far I thought that in ES6 function shorthand is

```
let sum = (a, b)=>{
   return a + b;
}
```

How the first one is different from the second one ?

Comment: the second one can also be written - `let sum = (a, b)=> a + b;`

Comment: With `()=>()` the second set of parentheses is for grouping, so it doesn't need the `return` keyword that you'd need with `{}`.

Comment: @nnnnnn `() => (...)` is for React's JSX. It signifies the JSX if I'm not mistaken. But `=> {...}` creates a new block with statements while `=> (...)` is like `=> { return (...) }`. The value after the arrow is the returned value unless you create a new block - implicitly.

Comment: @AndrewLi - I don't use JSX, but `()=>()` is perfectly valid in plain (ES6) JS (assuming you actually put something inside the second parentheses).

Comment: @nnnnnn Agreed.

Comment: The difference is with the parens the function body must be a single expression; with braces it will be one or more statements.

Comment: @AndrewLi: The `(...)` have nothing to do with JSX. They seem to be added for readability only. They could as well be omitted without any change in functionality.

Comment: @FelixKling I've never thought about it that way, but that's correct. It's just grouping after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the ()=> () syntax imagine if there was an implicit return statment e.g. () => {return ()}

Comment: It would be highly useful to provide the correct terminology for this form, which is "concise body".

Answer (score 2):

`() => ()` is a one liner shorthand of `() => { doSomething() OR return; }`.

Anyways, if you need more manipulations and need more than one line statement, you should go for `() => {}` syntax otherwise you can use a shorthand syntax `() => ()`

The following are also treated as one line statement. But to use with `() => ()` syntax, you need to rewrite it without `return` statement,

```
// The below one line statement can be rewritten as below
if (true ) return something;

// rewritten of above one
() => ( a > b ? a : b)

// one line statement
if (true ) invoke();  // This will go like, () => (a ? a.invoke() : b.invoke())

// one line statement
for(var i in results) doSomething();

//And your jsx statement which can be tread as one liner
<Cell {...props}>
    <a href="#">{data.getObjectAt(rowIndex)[col]}</a>
  </Cell>
```

Comment: `(...) => (...);` is for returning JSX in stateless components in React. It's equivalent to `(...) => { return (...); }`. `(...)` signifies JSX.

Comment: yeah agreed, this `jsx` is treated as one line statement such as `if (true ) invoke();`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Unfortunately, I think I can't up vote with my current reputation.

Comment: *"() => () is a one liner shorthand of () => { doSomething() OR return; }."* No, it's would be equivalent to `() => { return (); }`.